# ¿Como puedo descargar archivos con php en una carpeta que esta fuera de public html o htdocs?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, download

he buscado por todos lados y no veo solución.

Me gustaría saber como puedo descargar un archivo con js y php el descargar un archivo que se encuentra fuera de la carpeta plublic

```
|_htdocs
       |_proyecto
          |_index.php     (<-aquí la etiqueta con <a> o boton para descargar el archvio)
          |_descargar.php (<- contiene el proceso de descarga path etc )
|_archivos (<- Aquí están ubicados los archivos que deseo descargar)
```

Encontré algunos ejemplos pero no me funcionan, por eso no dejo nada de código, pero es la lógica que estoy siguiendo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: También podrías implementar algún script para descargar archivos... por ejemplo /download.php?file=nombrearchivo.jpg. Y en download lees el archivo y lo mandas de vuelta en la respuesta

Comment: Eso mismo he tratado, pero al abrir el archivo en vez de descargar me lo imprime en el dom como si fuera un echo de php

Comment: Entonces probablemente te falta configurar bien los headers de la respuesta, puedes usar por ejemplo `application/octet-stream`

Answer (score 0):

Para rutas relativas, puede usar `__DIR__` directamente en lugar de `dirname(__FILE__)`

pudes obtener mas detalle en la respuesta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537477/how-to-use-dir)

que te dará la ruta en que te encuentras, de ahi puedes utilizar la sentencia [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) para convertir la ruta por con un arreglo, y ahi quitar las carpetas hasta llegar al la requerida

```
 <?php 
$rootpath = __DIR__;

$array_root = explode("/",$rootpath);

var_dump($array_root);
```